# How to compute sum all bytes in array (CRC)

Tags: c#, arrays, crc

I trying to get sum all bytes in array (CRC).

I have an array `0x3A, 0x07, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x04`.
CRC of this array is **`3A`**.

Or this array `0x3A 0x09 0x00 0x00 0x80 0x03 0x01 0x00`. CRC equals = **`38`**.

I checked many algorithms, but no one not gave me this result.

I'm checked this 
`(IEnumerable<byte> array) => (byte)(array.Sum(arr => arr) & 0xFF);`

and this:

```
byte crc = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    crc = crc8Table[(crc ^ data[i]) & 0xFF];
return crc;
```

or this:

```
byte checksum = 0x00;
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
     checksum ^= data[i];
```

But no one attempts no gave me a true result. How can I find an algorithm, that will give me CRC  **`3A`** or **`38`** for arrays.

Comment: Sooo.. How did you calc those CRCs?

Comment: OP asks us to reverse engineer the CRC.

Comment: This packet i'm got from WireShark.
I writing a program and me need to understand how to get this result.

Comment: What kind of packet?

Comment: that is command for device ```0x3A, 0x07, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x04, 0x3A``` and last index is CRC

Comment: This might help: https://crccalc.com/

Comment: But why do you need to calculate it yourself if you have a library that can do it for you?

Comment: me need to rewrite software to C# but i don't know an algorithm which to compute crc.
Software written on C may be C++. But i don't have a source...

Comment: See Sunshine website.  The is a calculator and sample code : http://www.sunshine2k.de/articles/coding/crc/understanding_crc.html and http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html

Comment: thx u all guys.

Answer (score 0):

Solution on my question.

```
byte b = 0xFF;
for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
     b -= data[i];

return b;
```